# Load needed markers for google map from web api and load others dynamically as camera move

Tags: android, google-maps, android-maps-v2

In my android application, I want to show markers on google map dynamically. I've lots of marker location data available through my web api, and need to load them according to what user need to see (for example just fetch markers which are belong to that part of map, and load others as camera move in async mode).

I've search a lot but cannot find any straight forward solution, my question is what is the best practice and solution to do such a functionality? Is there any provided guid for that?

P.S: I don't have any problem in loading all markers in android google map using cluster manager, but when the number of markers become large, it takes too much time to fetch all of them.

Comment: Either update your webapi to support a spatial query (using latlngbounds of screen on camera move) or use firebase/geofire which would then hold keys/webapi url for each marker and again use latlngbounds of screen to update the geofire query.

Comment: @Andy thanks for your comment, I update my api to get just locations inside my screen position...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use *Google map clustering* for more markers data.It will give you effective *Google map* experience. By clustering your markers, you can put a large number of markers on a map without making the map hard to read.

Here is the official documentation you can follow [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/utility/marker-clustering)

Sample Code.

```
// Declare a variable for the cluster manager.
private ClusterManager<MyItem> mClusterManager;

private void setUpClusterer() {
    // Position the map.
    getMap().moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new LatLng(51.503186, -0.126446), 10));

    // Initialize the manager with the context and the map.
    // (Activity extends context, so we can pass 'this' in the constructor.)
    mClusterManager = new ClusterManager<MyItem>(this, getMap());

    // Point the map's listeners at the listeners implemented by the cluster
    // manager.
    getMap().setOnCameraIdleListener(mClusterManager);
    getMap().setOnMarkerClickListener(mClusterManager);

    // Add cluster items (markers) to the cluster manager.
    addItems();
}

private void addItems() {

    // Set some lat/lng coordinates to start with.
    double lat = 51.5145160;
    double lng = -0.1270060;

    // Add ten cluster items in close proximity, for purposes of this example.
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        double offset = i / 60d;
        lat = lat + offset;
        lng = lng + offset;
        MyItem offsetItem = new MyItem(lat, lng);
        mClusterManager.addItem(offsetItem);
    }
}
```

By using this sample code you need to configure your api data to cluster as per your requirement and show markers on map.

Because of large number of markers data obviously it will take time to load into cluster manager and also depends on what network you connected on.

Comment: thanks for your answer, but I cannot understand how this help for loading data from web api? for example I have 100000 location data, should I load all of them at first? I think It's not efficient and take too much time in slow connection.

Comment: OnCameraIdleListener is the key to handle the api calling ... thank you